# JQuery Mobile destroyed my layout: how to disable autostyling?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I'm develping a website and I made all the design and the styling upon bootstrap and it is working fine. Then I wanted to add a panel for the mobile menu.

the panel is the one on the right of this example:[jQuery Mobile panels, click on the plus sign](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html)

I took the panel that comes out clicking on the plus, and I worked to add it to my website (with my menu instead of the form inside the panel).
It works fine, but adding the jQuery Mobile JS completely destroyed my layout, adding lot of ui-* classes around my code and the styles attached to them.

I've tried those things:

- disabling the css whole (but the panel does not work anymore)
- renaming selectively only the classes that makes more mess, but it is
  way too much work, just to fix a checkbox I had to rename several ui
  classes.
- fiddling with the js (the panel stopped working)

I just need the panel. I don't need all the creepy styling on the forms or other unwanted stuff.

Now I don't know what to do. There is another way to get this panel working withour all the mess? Why they did this js so intrusive?

Comment: you can download "panel widget" only http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ though, I wouldn't recommend doing so. There are plenty of stand-alone panels for mobile. or just create your own, it's simple.

Comment: Can you point me somewhere I can get a standalone panel that comes out from the right, or to a tutorial that teaches me how to do it? I've been looking on google for ages and just found this panel made with jquery mobile, it seems I just can't put the right words on google to get some decent results.

Comment: This is more or less the concept of panel. If you want to create custom events, listen to `transitionend` to fire them using `.trigger("custom event")` http://jsfiddle.net/bpbbkaf4/1/

Comment: Hi Cicciolina, thanks for the tip. Can I ask you where did you learn? I really need to improve my skills. I was looking around and I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryjqmob_panels_app.htm It is a very trimmed down example, but the css and the js it's all minified the way they need it. How does a professional do that? I use notepad++ and I see that's not the right tool for it.

Comment: Practicing is your friend. Here is another example that moves wrapper and reveals panel underneath http://jsfiddle.net/dtb5nuh3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
data-role="none"
```

If you  also want to disable mobile use in [mobileinit](https://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/) event:

```
$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
```

If you  have several elements use a function on start load page:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function( event ) {
      // add the data-role="none" to desired elements...
      $( "input, select", event.target ).attr( "data-role", "none" );
});
```

Comment: As I understood, I need to add "data-role" on each tag that is affected. I am talking about hundreds of tags. Can you give me an example for the initialize? Where should I put it? In the html between the scripts tag or somewhere else?

Comment: check my edit, you can put dinamically by a function, not super-elegant but will do the trick

Comment: I'm sure it's my fault, but I've placed you code in the <script></script> inside the index.php page and it does nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Terix This is not a solution; it will cause you headache and WTF on the long run. Just discard jquery mobile if you are not intending to use all its features.

Comment: did you debugged it? do you have some pattern in the elements or you want to select them all? if so you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("*");`